# Error while running Daemon class in java?

Tags: java, linux, daemon, noclassdeffounderror, jsvc

I am trying to make a Daemon class in java so I have implemented a class which implements Daemon but when I run it, I always get errors.

The class that I use for that is ;

```
public class RemoteAgentDaemon implements Daemon {
    private Logger logger;
    public LocalAgent frame;

    public void destroy() {
        logger.info("Server was destroyed ....");
    }

    public void init(DaemonContext arg0) throws Exception {
        frame = new LocalAgent();
        logger = Logger.getLogger("daemon");
        logger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout("%d{DATE} [%t] %5p - %m%n")));
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Server was started ....");
        frame.listenSocket();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Server was stoped ....");
    }
}
```

And the script that I use for running the daemon is ;

```
#!/bin/sh

# Setup variables
EXEC=/usr/bin/jsvc
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
CLASS_PATH="/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar":"/home/mehmet/Desktop/remoteAgent.jar"
CLASS=example.Main
USER=foo
PID=/tmp/example.pid
LOG_OUT=/tmp/example.out
LOG_ERR=/tmp/example.err

do_exec()
{
    $EXEC -home "$JAVA_HOME" -cp $CLASS_PATH -user $USER -outfile $LOG_OUT -errfile $LOG_ERR -pidfile $PID $1 $CLASS
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        do_exec
            ;;
    stop)
        do_exec "-stop"
            ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f "$PID" ]; then
            do_exec "-stop"
            do_exec
        else
            echo "service not running, will do nothing"
            exit 1
        fi
            ;;
    *)
            echo "usage: daemon {start|stop|restart}" >&2
            exit 3
            ;;
esac
```

When I run the script I got this error;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2444)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2687)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:129)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
... 5 more
    Cannot load daemon
    Service exit with a return value of 3
```

Can you please help me to solve this ?

Thank you all

EDIT :

now I have changed my class path to ;

CLASS_PATH="/home/mehmet/Desktop/apache-log4j-1.2.16":"/home/mehmet/Desktop/remoteAgent.jar"

but now I got an error ;

Cannot find daemon loader org/apache/commons/daemon/support/DaemonLoader Service exit with a return value of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
```

The above indicates that you should add log4j to your classpath (edit `CLASS_PATH` in the script with the location of your log4j jar)

Comment: now I have changed my class path to ;

CLASS_PATH="/home/mehmet/Desktop/apache-log4j-1.2.16":"/home/mehmet/Desktop/remoteAgent.jar"

but now I got an error ;

Cannot find daemon loader org/apache/commons/daemon/support/DaemonLoader
Service exit with a return value of 1

Comment: I think you forgot `"/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar"` in the classpath now

Comment: I redownloaded the daemon dependency and added to CLASS_PATH using;   export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/mehmet/Desktop/commons-daemon-1.0.7 but it still gives the error

Answer (score 0):

you miss log4j.jar. commons.daemon has a dependency on it.